# Error in Android build.gradle file: Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I am getting the following build error. Can you please help me to fix it.

```
 Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-core-utils:29.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.android.support:design:29.*.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Comment: Please share contents of your build.gradle file (app module).

Answer (score 1):

There is no version 29 of the `com.android.support` artifacts.  The latest version of them (also outdated) is `28.0.0`.  You should [migrate to the new `androidx` artifacts](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).